# The formula for $\cos nx$ without Demoivre's theorem?

Tags: trigonometry

De Moirve's theorem easily derives $\cos\left(nx\right)$ in terms of decreasing powers of $\cos\left(x\right)$ and increasing powers of $\sin\left(x\right)$. 
But I'd like to use trignomoetry to derive this simple recursion.
I have tried but the recursion soon gets too complex.

Is there a trignometric way ?.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula check the induction way, for example.

Comment: no lol, induction assumes the formula, i asked the derivation. moreover it has something to do with chebseyn or sth polynomials.

Comment: Ahhh! Forgive me xD mmm What about trying, in a tedious way, from the power $2$ like

$$(\cos x + i\sin x)^2 = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x + 2i\sin x \cos x$$

And then use some trig identity like $\sin^2 = 1 - cos^2$ or $\cos^2 = \frac{1}{2}(1 + 2\cos)$ et cetera...

Hope it will help!

Comment: no this is more fundamentally derived using trig, without cosx+isinx which uses complex numbers.

Comment: more this question hasnt been asked before and i dont find the proof on the internet too.

Comment: I don't want to say something wrong but probably there is no way. I mean, the formula arises from $e^{i\theta}$ which arises from Taylor Series. You expand, you collect even and odd terms and voilà the result when you "powerize" it. To prove it in a different way would be cool but I have to admit my lack of knowledge about! Good question though, imo.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Use the *Recursive Identity*:

\begin{align}
\cos\pars{nx} & =
-\cos\pars{\bracks{n - 2}x} + 2\cos\pars{\bracks{n - 1}x}\cos\pars{x}
\end{align}

> For instance,

\begin{align}
\cos\pars{4x} &= -\cos\pars{2x} + 2\cos\pars{3x}\cos\pars{x}
\\[5mm] & =
-\cos\pars{2x} +
2\bracks{-\cos\pars{x} + 2\cos\pars{2x}\cos\pars{x}}\cos\pars{x}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{-1 + 4\cos^{2}\pars{x}}\cos\pars{2x} - 2\cos^{2}\pars{x}
\\[5mm] &=
\bracks{-1 + 4\cos^{2}\pars{x}}\bracks{-1 + 2\cos^{2}\pars{x}} - 2\cos^{2}\pars{x}
\\[5mm] & =\bbx{\ds{%
8\cos^{4}\pars{x}} - 8\cos^{2}\pars{x} + 1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

We may prove that $\cos(nx)$ is always a polynomial in $\cos(x)$ in a quite simple way.

> **Claim:** for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\cos(nx)=T_n(\cos x)$ where $T_n(z)$ is a polynomial with degree $n$.

**Proof:** The claim is trivial for $n=0$ ($T_0(z)=1$) and for $n=1$ ($T_1(z)=z$). 
By the cosine addition formulas,
$$\cos(nx)+\cos((n+2)x) = 2\cos(x)\cos((n+1)x) \tag{1}$$
or
$$ \cos((n+2)x) = 2\cos(x)\cos((n+1)x)-\cos(nx).\tag{2} $$
The last identity provides a way for proving the claim by induction, since it gives:
$$ T_{n+2}(z) = 2z\cdot T_{n+1}(z)-T_{n}(z).\tag{3}$$
If $T_n(z)$ and $T_{n+1}(z)$ are polynomials with degree $n$ and $n+1$, by $(3)$ we have that $T_{n+2}(z)$ is a polynomial with degree $1+\partial T_{n+1}=n+2$.

---

These polynomials are commonly known as [Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html).
The explicit formula
$$ T_n(z) = \sum_{r=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^r}{n-r}\binom{n-r}{r}(2z)^{n-2r}\tag{4}$$
is equivalent to

$$\cos(nx) = \sum_{r=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^r}{n-r}\binom{n-r}{r}(2\cos x)^{n-2r}\tag{5} $$
and $(4)$, too, can be proved by induction on $n$ through $(3)$.

---

If we consider that, by construction, the roots of $T_n(z)$ are given by $\cos\left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2n}\right)$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$, and that [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) gives a neat set of relations between the elementary symmetric function of the roots and the coefficients of a polynomial, $(4)$ gives us a way for evaluating many interesting trigonometric sums, like, for instance:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2n}\right)=\frac{n}{2}.$$

Comment: D I think you are mistaken, i asked for cos(nx) formula in terms of powers of sinx and cosx, the same you get when e^(ix). How its derived, or even related to  chebyshev polynomials at all, as they are expressed only in terms of cosx itself?

Comment: @koe: way beyond obvious: an even function of $e^{ix}$ is a function of $\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Chebyshev polynomials](https://brilliant.org/wiki/chebyshev-polynomials-definition-and-properties/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this OK? [Trigonometry Cosine Multiple Angle Formulae](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/trigonometry/multipleAngles.htm) from Ken Ward's Mathematics Pages.